# Fortran 90 Error: END tag label not defined

Tags: file-io, fortran

I'm at a beginner level in FORTRAN. 
I need to use the READ-Opiton END. But i get an Error that there is no END tag label defined... 
Here is my Code:

```
    subroutine readfiles

implicit none


integer :: N, l
real, allocatable :: pos(:,:)

N = 2 !Number of Lines

allocate(orte(N,3))

open (unit=99, file='positions.txt', status='old', action='read',)
do l=1,N
  read (99,* ,END=999) pos(l,1), pos(l,2), pos(l,3)
enddo
do l=1,N
    print *, pos(l,1), pos(l,2), pos(l,3)
enddo

return
END subroutine readfiles
```

And here is the error:

```
gfortran -c -O3 -fdefault-real-8 -I/usr/include readfiles.f90
readfiles.f90:22.25:

  read (99,* ,END=999) pos(l,1), pos(l,2), pos(l,3)
                     1
Error: END tag label 999 at (1) not defined
make: *** [readfiles.o] Fehler 1
```

Any Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you need a line number labeled 999 to which control is transferred when the end of the file is reached, as shown below.

```
        subroutine readfiles

    implicit none


    integer :: N, l
    real, allocatable :: pos(:,:)

    N = 2 !Number of Lines

    allocate(orte(N,3))

    open (unit=99, file='positions.txt', status='old', action='read',)
    do l=1,N
      read (99,* ,END=999) pos(l,1), pos(l,2), pos(l,3)
    enddo
    999 continue
    N = l-1
    do l=1,N
        print *, pos(l,1), pos(l,2), pos(l,3)
    enddo

return
END subroutine readfiles
```

Btw I advise against using variables named "l", since "l" looks like 1.